# Canvas bitmap is not being saved

Tags: android, android-canvas

i am new to android canvas and i failed to get solution of my problem,
the problem is:
I am using canvas in two modes AvoidXfermode.Mode.TARGET(to remove occurence of a single color) and PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR(to erase a part of my canvas).

everything independently is working perfect
but in my code i want to use both of them in such a way that when i choose i want to erase a particular color it should erase it, and my code is doing so,

but after removing that particular color when i am switching my mode to eraser mode...everything which was deleted using AvoidXfermode comes back.

i am doing these things on a bitmap,
my onDraw method is:

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawBitmap(DrawBitmap, 0, 0, DrawBitmapPaint);
        if (flag != 1) {
            setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            for (Path p : paths) {

                canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
                Bitmap bitmap = getDrawingCache();
                DrawBitmap = bitmap;



                //
            }
            //canvas.setBitmap(bitmap.isMutable() ? bitmap : bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true));

        } else if (flag == 1) {
            if (touchx > mCanvas.getWidth() || touchy > mCanvas.getHeight() || touchx < 0 || touchy < 0) {
                return;
            }
            for (Path p : paths) {

                color = DrawBitmap.getPixel(touchx, touchy);
                mPaint.setXfermode(new AvoidXfermode(color, 100, AvoidXfermode.Mode.TARGET));
                mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                canvas.drawPaint(mPaint);

                setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap bitmap = getDrawingCache();
                DrawBitmap = bitmap;
            }



        }


    }
```

everything is declared in onDraw for now just for the this question,
and the code where i switch my mode is:

```
 case R.id.erase:
            mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
            mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(40);
            flag = 0;
            break;

 case R.id.DELETE:

            flag = 1;
            break;
```

the code where i am creating my canvas is:

```
 DrawBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MainActivity.this.getResources(), R.drawable.sample);
    DrawBitmap = DrawBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(DrawBitmap);
    mPath = new Path();
    paths.add(mPath);
    DrawBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
```

i am wrong somewhere,but i don't know where, any suggestions would be helpful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bitmap = getDrawingCache();
DrawBitmap = bitmap;
```

Your logic is a lot complicated. I specifically mean the above lines of code. You have `mCanvas` that is backed up with the `DrawBitmap` bitmap. Then you have the `canvas` of `onDraw()` which is backed by it's own bitmap. The thing you need to understand is whatever you draw in `DrawBitmap` stays or as you would call it "saved". Anything that is drawn via `canvas` is subjected to change during the next call to `onDraw()`.

So if you want to save something in `DrawBitmap` use the `mCanvas`. The moment you want to save the state of the user's drawing, draw it in `mCanvas`. You could just draw everything on `mCanvas` and at the end of `onDraw()`, you can call `canvas.drawBitmap(DrawBitmap, 0, 0, DrawBitmapPaint);` This way everything that is done by the user is saved every step of the way.

Comment: thanks for the response, i want to learn canvas in depth,if possible suggest some links, and in relation to this question i also noticed that whenever i am switching my mode that is from  AvoidXfermode  to eraser mode everything is coming back again.

Comment: and if i am only using mCanvas nothing is being drawn..:(

Comment: what i wish to make is an app like photo layer by handycloset. the feature of auto erasing background and manual erasing.